# How to get Safari Intelligent Tracking Prevention

Tags: safari, privacy

How can I get Apple's Intelligent Tracking Prevention in Safari Web browser?

Is it dependent on my Safari version, my macOS version, or both? If so, which versions?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it dependent on my Safari version, my macOS version, or both? If so, which versions?

Intelligent Tracking Prevention was first introduced in Safari 11 in macOS High Sierra 10.13 along with iOS 11 both of which were released in September 2017. It is available in macOS 10.13, iOS 11 and later.

The same can be configured by going to Safari Preferences → Privacy → Website tracking: Prevent cross site tracking.

To configure the same in iOS, go to Settings app → Safari → Prevent Cross-Site Tracking.

ITP2 went into affect in iOS 12/Safari 12 during an update release. This update to ITP includes workarounds that marketers created.

You can upgrade to Safari 12 while running macOS 10.12 Sierra. Safari 12 release notes can be referred to here:

- [Safari version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_12)

Comment: So I can't use it if I have macOS 10.12, for example, then. You mention ITP2, but only with regards to iOS. Is it not available for macOS?

Comment: ITP is available in Safari 11. ITP2 was released with Safari 12. You can upgrade to Safari 12 while running macOS 10.12 Sierra. Release notes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_12

Comment: In Safari 12 on macOS 10.12 in Safari Preferences → Privacy, it says only "Ask websites not to track me" (which I thought was simply the "Do Not Track" feature). Nowhere does it say "Prevent cross site tracking". I am therefore confused as to whether Safari 12 / macOS 10.12 has ITP.

Comment: @forthrin It's the same thing. The Prevent cross-site tracking terminology is from Safari 12 running on macOS Mojave 10.14. You can refer to the Safari release notes which I have linked to in the answer above.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Quite confusing, I must say. At any rate, I'm getting poor results when testing Safari on tracking testing sites, so either I don't have ITP, or ITP is not very good. I posted a separate question about this.